# How to get some data from list and create another list with that data in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have I case where I got one Object from API. This Object containts ArrayList. This ArrayList containts objects with data I need as another list.

I have this code and it works just fine

```
Observable<SomePresentationModel> observable = apiService.getData()
    .map(data -> {
      List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Bar bar : data.getBars()) {
        foo.addAll(bar.getSomething());
      }
      return asPresentationModel(foo);
    });
```

But it looks terrible and I'm sure there is some way to do it better but I don't know how, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMapIterable` / `toList` to emits item from your list, and rebuild a list after (see bellow). Please note that `toList` will work only if `apiServiceService.getData()` return an `Observable` that complete. Otherwise, it won't emit the list.

```
Observable<SomePresentationModel> observable = apiService.getData()
              .flatMapIterable(data -> data.getBars())
              .map(elt -> elt.getSomething())
              .toList()
              .map(foo -> asPresentationModel(foo));
```